# Rails - showing comments in a different area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, models, posts

Im trying to create a system which allows athletes to respond to their coaches traing plan, to do this i have allowed the coach to create contentsm however i am using a blogging based system to create it... at the moment the page displays like so

CONTENT TITLE

Content info 1...

Content info 2...

Content info 3...

COMMENTS...

comment 1

comment 2

comment 3

.etc

However  i want to set it so that there can only be 7 Comments Max per post as well as set out like this per post...

CONTENT TITLE

Content info 1...

comment 1

Content info 2...

comment 2

Content info 3...

comment 3

.etc

I realise this is probably not the best way to do want i want, but it works (just dosnt appear in the place i want it to)
I did do experiments with creating more models, but kept getting errors whenever i tryed to run more than 1 comment system per post. I was wondering if i could have some help in sorting this out, or any methods i could do to make this easier, or even better if the models would work and if i was just doing something wrong?? tell me if this isn't enough information to go off, and ill try provide some more! Thankyou

.

.

EDIT:

The models i have used are
Program - As in the training plan set for the week
Coaches - The coach that is inputing the data to the rider
Riders - To comment on the coaches data with their own data.

I am unsure what files are need exactly so i have included the link to the github page i am pushing to ( https://github.com/effectonedesign/coacheasy1 ), if there is any other info needed, please let me know!

I like what "mind" has said however, i have done everything have said, in my def show (program controller) it is saying there is an error and i keep getting this message undefined method `coaches' for nil:NilClass everything is identical to his but im getting issues, i really do appreciate the help! Thanks

Comment: Please add your models (content & comment mainly) and try to add your templates you work with

Comment: In your `Coach` model `belongs_to :programs` should be `belongs_to :program`. You should post your code in your question on StackOverflow, not link to it. So a good place to start is where you get your error - post the related view and controller action for where you're getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create 3 models for the above, `TrainingPlan`, `Section` (or content, text_block etc.) and `Comment`.

Then do the following

- TrainingPlan has_many :sections
- Section belongs_to :training_plan
- Section has_one :comment (if you allow only 1 comment per section, otherwise use has_many)
- Comment belongs_to :section

Now, to achieve the formatting you wanted do the following in your views:

```
<% @training_plan.sections.each do |section| %>
  <%= section.text %>
  <%= section.comment.text %>
<% end %>
```

If you allow multiple comments:

```
<% @training_plan.sections.each do |section| %>
  <%= section.text %>
  <% section.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.text %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

#### Form for comments

I haven't tested the following, so you might need to tweak some parts.
The training plan controller:

```
def show
  # using includes will query the database 3 times only (once for each table) rather than
  # querying it 1 + N + N (in this case 7 sections, 7 comments possibly, so 15 times)
  @training_plan = TrainingPlan.includes(:sections, sections: :comment).find(params[:id])
  @sections = @training_plan.sections
  @sections.each do |section|
    # only build a new comment if there is no comment for that section already
    section.build_comment unless section.comment
  end
end
```

In your view views/training_plans/show.html.erb

```
<%= @training_plan.title %> # or whatever
<% @sections.each do |section|
  <%= @section.content %>
  <% if section.comment %>
    <%= section.comment.content %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'comments/form', comment: section.comment %> # or wherever you have the form
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

views/comments/_form.html.erb

```
# This might break if you have a separate comment action somewhere which passes an
# instance variable @comment to the form
<%= form_for comment do |f| %>
  # normal form stuff
<% end %>
```

If that all works then on your training plan show page you should see each section, and if it has a comment then that comment will be rendered, otherwise a form will be shown.

Depending on your routes you might need to run `rake routes` and see where your comment create action is, and then pass that to the form `<%= form for comment, url: some_url_helper_here do |comment| %>`

If it was me I would create the add comment part through JavaScript, sort of like in [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2), but since you're new to RoR I've tried to keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse, is there any way to PM you for more info/help please, im still confused (new to RoR)! i would really really appreciate it! thankyou!!

Comment: Mind.blank, how would I have this so that it also produces a for to create a new comment for each comment section :)? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, still got some issues...
my models are (yours vs mine)
yours - TrainingPlan vs mine - Program(s)
yours - Section vs mine - coach(es)
yours - Comment vs mine - rider(s)

i have done everything you have said above, in my _def show_ (program controller) it is saying there is an error and i keep getting this message _undefined method `coaches' for nil:NilClass_

everything is identical to yours but im getting issues, i really do appreciate the help!